# Sharepoint permissions conflict with Microsoft Graph "Application" type permissions?

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

I have a problem when I want to query a sharepoint list with Microsot Graph. I have no results.

The sharepoint list has these item-level permissions:

- Read Access : Read items that were created by the user
- Create and Edit access : Create items and edit items that were created by the user

Azure AD Graph Permissions

- Type application : Sites.Read.All - Admin consent OK - I'm using this permission because I'm creating an API.

My credentials are correct because I can see another list of sharepoint that doesn't have these item-level permissions.

I also tried with Graph Explorer via azure but this time with a sharepoint admin user. I only have my account as a result

With the same account, if I request the sharepoint API directly on my browser (_api/web/lists/getbytitle('list')/items, I see all items of the sharepoint list.

Do you have any ideas on this behavior which limits access to data via microsoft graph ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was facing a similar issue and it seems to work with Sites.Manage.All (see [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference#sites-permissions)) even though the documentation is very unclear at this point. Would be cool to hear back if that works for you.

Comment: Thank you! It works with this permission :) Indeed the documentation should be more detailed on this point.